# python lxml.etree._Element to JSON or dict

Tags: python, json, lxml

From one method of library I get `lxml.etree._Element`, is there any library or function to convert an `lxml.etree._Element` to JSON or a dictionary?

For example:

```
<detail>
    <ouaf:Fault xmlns:ouaf="urn:oracle:ouaf">
        <ResponseStatus>F</ResponseStatus>
        <ResponseCode>2013</ResponseCode>
        <ResponseData numParm="1"  text="The personal account was not found: 9134211141"  category="90006"  number="32200"  parm1="9134211141"  />
    </ouaf:Fault>
</detail>
```

Should be something like this:

```
{
    'detail': {
        'Fault': {
            'ResponseStatus': 'F'
            'ResponseCode': '2013'
            'ResponseData': {
                'numParm': '1'
                'text': 'The personal account was not found: 9134211141'
                'category': '90006'
                'number': '32200'
                'parm1': '9134211141'
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Update 1:

When I trying use this [function](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-map-an-xml-tree-into-a-dict-of-dicts)

```
def conver_element(self, element):
        foo = self.recursive_dict(element)
        return foo

def recursive_dict(self, element):
    return element.tag, \
           dict(map(self.recursive_dict, element)) or element.text
```

And I get foo:

```
<class 'tuple'>: ('detail', {'ResponseCode': '2013', 'ResponseStatus': 'F', 'ResponseData': None})
```

Comment: Do you know what an `_Element` is? It is an element from an XML file. In order to *convert* something, you first need an **encoding**: a set of rules what you define to be acceptable output. Please update your question with these specifications?

Comment: Maybe http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-map-an-xml-tree-into-a-dict-of-dicts

Comment: @har07 Thx, but it's not parse 'ResponseData'. I search library cuz it will take time and experience to make it work clearly and I haven't enough experience and knowledge)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you have tried that, post [minimal but complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code demonstrating how you tried it, show your current output, and explain what's the problem with that code..

Comment: @har07 I added code in update

Answer (score 2):

The `recursive_dict` method in the linked documentation doesn't include XML attribute in the result. Assuming, for XML element that has attribute and *doesn't have content* (self-closing tag) you want to get the attributes as the dictionary value, the following modified version of `recursive_dict` will do :

```
def recursive_dict(element):
    if element.text == None and len(element.attrib):
        return element.tag, element.attrib
    return element.tag, \
            dict(map(recursive_dict, element)) or element.text
```

Comment: This solution might lead to data loss due to its assumptions. For different solution see https://gist.github.com/jacobian/795571